# What is the intuitive interpretation of the $dF$ measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, intuition

If I have a cumulative distribution function $F$, I can define an associated measure $\mu((a,b]) = F(b)-F(a)$. But how exactly can I interpret this measure? What would $\int f d\mu$ intuitively mean?

Comment: Presumably you meant $F(b)-F(a)$. Think of $\mu(a,b]$ as the 'weight' of $(a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat, I eddited. Weights? Hmmm...

Comment: $\int f d\mu$ is the expectation $\mathbb{E}_X[f(X)]$, no?

Comment: It is same as the Stieltje's integral $\int fdF$.